# Highlight/change font color when new input comes in

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am currently have a textbox which is pre-populated with text. For instance, `Hello World`.

So if I were to key in new input, example, `Hello World Hello`, i wanted to highlight/change the font color of the new input which is `Hello`

Is it possible to be done?

Comment: simple textbox doesn't support this behaviour.

Comment: why not to use jquery?

Answer (score 2):

By default text box doesn't support different styling for the changes found.
Use custom rich textbox instead.
check the below url for reference.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/01/13/writing-colorized-text-to-richtextbox/

Answer (score 0):

Use Css for this

```
input:focus { 
  background-color: yellow;
  color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use default text box to do the styling. You can use WYSIWYG editor.